# Ext.Ajax.request is not passing parameter correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs

I am tried to passing param to server in order to delete request but it is not working.
Here is my Ext.Ajax.request using URL: deluserHistorygrid.asp.

function (btn) {
                            if (btn == 'yes') {

```
                            var id = record.get('EventID');
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: 'delUserHistoryGrid.asp',
                                async: false,
                                method: 'POST',
                                params: {
                                    id: id
                                },
                                timeout: 30000,
                                success: function (result) {

                                    Ext.Msg.show({
                                        title: 'Deleted!',
                                        msg: 'The request for ' + id + ' was deleted from the calendar.',
                                        width: 260,
                                        closable: true,
                                        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
                                    });

                                    userHistoryStore.remove(grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex));
                                    userinfoStore.reload();

                                }
                            });
```

Inside my deluserHistoryGrid.asp

I have variable set as following:

```
       Dim vntPostedData, lngCount
       Dim record, strSQL
       Dim varFlxId

       varFlxId =  Request("id")

       lngCount = Request.TotalBytes
       vntPostedData = SimpleBinaryToString(Request.BinaryRead(lngCount))
       'Response.BinaryWrite vntPostedData

       'Set record = JSON.parse(vntPostedData)  

       sSQL = "DELETE FROM VacationCalendar WHERE RecordID = " & varFlxId
       Response.write sSQL & "</br>"

       Set oRS = dbConn.Execute( sSQL ) 

       Function SimpleBinaryToString(Binary)
       'SimpleBinaryToString converts binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY Or MultiByte string)
      'to a string (BSTR) using MultiByte VBS functions
      Dim I, S

      For I = 1 To LenB(Binary)
      S = S & Chr(AscB(MidB(Binary, I, 1)))
      Next

      SimpleBinaryToString = S
      End Function
```

I am tried to passing the parameter Ext.Ajax.Request({params: {id:id}}) to delete requestID but it not working pls help me. I am new to that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to delete a record in the grid by sending that request? If that is the case it is usually not done this way.

It is enough if you configure grid store with proxy and writer. If you then remove the record from the store locally and then call `store.sync()`, Ext sends the request to the server so you only need to implement the server-side logic.

If you want to see a grid with all CRUD operations implemented go to [Editable and Writable ExtJS Grid Example](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#writable-grid).

Comment: I am tried to delete record on my Grid tables but It's somehow not delete via Ext.ajax.request({}). from my database. It only deleted from the browser. I am tired to rewrite some method to passing parameter {id: 'id'} via ADODB query in a separate file (deluserHistoryGrid.asp) by following query statement DELETE above. And it is still not passing parameter. How can write a code to pass the parameter correctly based on my issue above.

Comment: Delete is two step process: 1. Delete from the local store and 2. Call `store.sync()` - this 2nd step sends the request; you only need to process it on the server and delete the record from the server database.